# Need to fund sum of numbers in a string, excluding strings with a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I need to count sum of all numbers in a string which contains both numbers and strings, for instance ('abc123rv.rv1').

I created a forLoop and made everything crystal clear, but it does not work for some reason.

```
function count(str) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (typeof str[i] === 'number') sum += str[i]

  }

  return sum;
}
```

What am I missing here? And, I'd appreciate if you could share other ways of solving this, perhaps with a filter, map or reduce? Or maybe some other ways I'm missing.
Thank you all guys in advance. I'm happy that you're very active and always reply to my threads and help me with my questions, however, stupid they may seem to senior selves like you are!

Comment: `str[i]` will always be string. Try `sum += isNan(str[i]) ? 0 : Number(str[i])`

Comment: use `parseInt(str[i],10)`

Comment: in your example you want `1 + 2 + 3 + 1` or `123 + 1`?

Answer (score 4):

Any indexed value of a string will also be a (one character long) string.

I'd `.replace` all non-digit characters with the empty string, then sum up with `reduce`:

```js
function count(str) {
  return [...str.replace(/\D/g, '')]
    .reduce((a, b) => a + +b, 0);
}
console.log(count('abc123rv.rv1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the parse the number. If it got parsed then add it.

```js
function count(str) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(str[i],10)){ sum += parseInt(str[i],10)}

  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(count('abc123rv.rv1kaushik221)'))
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop through the string you have to [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) that into an array. Then convert the character to number and check whether that character is not a number or not using [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

```js
function count(str) {
  let sum = 0;
  str = str.split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i] = Number(str[i])
    if (!isNaN(str[i])) sum += str[i]
  }

  return sum;
}
console.log(count('abc123rv.rv1'));
```